# Making an exception class and leaving it empty

Tags: java, exception

Now I've created an exception class but haven't created a constructor for it as shown

```
public class InvalidChoiceException extends Exception {
}
```

but the catch block for that handles what I want to display.

```
try {
    if(readFile.hasNextInt() == false)
        throw new InputMismatchException();
    else {
        num = readFile.nextInt();
        readFile.nextLine();
    }
}  catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.err.println("Integer expected");
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Is this ok to do?

edit: Let's just pretend input mismatch was a empty exception class even though it's not..

Comment: Of course. Why wouldn't it be? Also - where are you using `InvalidChoiceException`?

Comment: Did you mean to use `InvalidChoiceException` in your example? Also, the compiler will (attempt to) provide a default constructor for your class if you haven't specified one. Success of that operation depends on your class' superclass.

Comment: You may want to look at the existing exceptions before creating a new one. If there's something in the standard set that comes close to your intended meaning, it usually makes more sense to use that rather than inventing your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an empty subclass of Exception is certainly allowed.
The only catch is that you will not be able tag any instance with an error message or cause (these are the standard piece of information that are usually associated to an Exception).

However if your use case doesn't require you to specify messages or causes of your exceptions you are good with such a design.